# Extract the SQL query that was run in the Oracle connector from a DataStage job in order to add it to a file/table

Tags: datastage

I have a parallel DataStage job that uses a particular SQL query with some parameters. Once the job is running, I can see in the Director log the exact SQL query that was triggered on the database.

My question is: **is there any way I can get this SQL query with all parameters replaced in the Designer job**, so I can add the code in a column from a table (a metadata column that will contain the exact query that was used for that particular run). In my job I can have a transformer that will put the query from the Oracle connector as a derivation for a column in the target table.

Thank you!

Comment: If you have parameters, just write them to file. The query is written in the stage, so copy it and replace all the parameters with your values.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the query from the log using log-reading functions (in a server routine) or options (in dsjob command). Design the writing part however you want.